# Value mismatch while passing attribute from Servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Setting value in Servlet and retrieving it in jsp using RequestDispatcher

**In test1Servlet :**

request.setAttribute("Alpha",alpha);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Test.jsp");

rd.forward(request, response);

**In Test.jsp:**
On click of button am doing ajax call to another servlet with request attribute values

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".button1").click(function(){
            $.ajax({

  type: "POST",

  url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/test2Servlet", 

 data: {"alpha":<%=request.getAttribute("alpha")%>,"ins":10},

 dataType:"text",
```

In this case if I set alpha value as 0017 in test1Servlet, am getting 0015 in jsp.

How this value is getting changed ?

Anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: It's not possible. You must be changing it somewhere in between. Can you post the full code for servlet and JSP.

Comment: Post a [mcve] along with an **exact** description of the input and the expected and unexpected output. Namely, you forgot to show how you're declaring and reading those variables. The values you used have octal notation instead of decimal notation thus chances are big that you made mistakes there.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you have still trouble, provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is no error there. You get the right value.
In many languages number preceded by zero are interpreted as octals or hexadezimal:

- OCTAL: 017 = 15
  (because the 1 is evaluated to 8 an the 7 as it is. So 1×8+7=15).
- hexadecimal: 0x17 = 1×16 + 7 = 23

Try it:

```
<script>
    var x = 0017;
    var y = 0x17;
    alert("x:" + x);
    alert("y:" + y);
</script>
```

Since the post parameters are converted to strings, you can put the values in quotes. Or avoid leading zeros in numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right but not sure where it's changing to octal because am getting the values from session and storing it as string and used same value in request.setAttribute(alpha).

Comment: getting value from session using below code and I can't ignore preceding  zero's




HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 String alpha=request.getParameter("alpha");
session.setAttribute("alpha", alpha);

Comment: How do you set `alpha` in test1Servlet? What type is it? Show the definition.

Comment: With putting the values in quotes i mean the jsp ajax call: 
 `data: {"alpha": '<%=request.getAttribute("alpha")%>',"ins":10}`. With single quotes around the `<%...%>`.